# Frequency of a wavelet filter

Tags: wavelet, mathematica

1. Assume that I have decomposed a data set using Symlet Wavelet with six levels. How can I estimate the approximate frequency interval of each level?
   That would be great if you consider your answer in the Mathematica environment.
2. If the above dataset describes turbulent velocity field, how I can decide up to which level is the bulk velocity? I need to separate the turbulent fluctuations from the mean.

The sampling frequency is 1 Hz and the duration of observation is 25 hours.

Comment: detail1:1/2-1Hz, detail2:1/4-1/2Hz; detail3:1/8-1/4Hz; detail4:1/16-1/8Hz, etc ...

Comment: You may try the second Q on [Physics.SE](http://physics.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @RockScience: So, from what you said, I may infer that the finest frequencies could be resolved by wavelets directly depends on the length of time series. right?

Comment: @K-1: The highest frequency is indeed linked to the total length of the time serie, whereas the smallest frequency is linked to the sampling frequency. No surprise here. About your second question, how do you define "turbulent fluctuations"? What is your defnition of noise? Without that you cannot separate the two parts of the time serie.

Comment: @RockScience: From the Nyquist sampling theorem, the maximum frequency equals half of sampling frequency. Therefore, the smallest frequency is linked to the total length of data. Is it not so? Thanks for the answer though. Could you please help me in my question about wavelet packet frequency range of each decomposition?

Answer (score -1):

```
% Calculate the frequency bands for the wavelet decomposition-------------
if Nf == 0
    Nf = log(fds/f)/log(2);     % number of decomposition levels
    Nf = double(uint32(Nf));
end
D = freq_bands( f, fds, Nf );
%Nf=no of level
%fds=Fs/ds;
%Fs=sampling freq
%ds=decimation factor for downsapling=1 or greater
%f=fund freq
```

Comment: To make your answer more useful for novice readers, could you perhaps give a little discussion or explanation for your code?